# TexPad Citation

Tags: bibliographies, apacite, texpad

I'm currently writing my thesis and use TexPad as my editor. I made the choice to use it as it looks clean, side-by-side pdf view and just works. Well almost works as I'm pulling my hair out as my references are only showing up as `(?, ?)` in the text.

This is the structure of my document:

```
\documentclass[10.5pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
            left=3.35cm,right=2.12cm,top=3.75cm,bottom=2.88cm,%
            footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[numberedbib]{apacite}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\quelle}[1]{\par\raggedleft\footnotesize Quelle:~#1}

\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}


\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{glossary}

\begin{document}

\include{cover}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\begin{abstract}
Lorem Ipsum
\end{abstract}

\end{otherlanguage}

\newpage

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\include{document1)
% All of my text
\include{document99)

\clearpage

\printglossaries

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references}
```

As you can see I separate each section of my thesis into their own files and then include them.

This is my unedited BibDesk file:

```
%% This BibTeX bibliography file was created using BibDesk.
%% https://bibdesk.sourceforge.io/

%% Created for MY NAME at 2020-03-09 14:33:56 +0100 


%% Saved with string encoding Unicode (UTF-8) 

@article{strava-millitary,
    Author = {BBC},
    Date-Added = {2020-03-09 13:59:08 +0100},
    Date-Modified = {2020-03-09 14:00:40 +0100},
    Journal = {BBC},
    Title = {Fitness app Strava lights up staff at military bases},
    Url = {https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-42853072},
    Year = {2018},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-42853072}}

@article{have-I-been-pwned,
    Date-Added = {2020-03-09 13:53:45 +0100},
    Date-Modified = {2020-03-09 13:55:58 +0100},
    Lastchecked = {09.03.2020},
    Month = {03},
    Title = {Have I been pwned},
    Url = {https://haveibeenpwned.com/PwnedWebsites},
    Year = {2020},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {https://haveibeenpwned.com/PwnedWebsites}}

@article{quantifying-explainable-discrimination,
    Author = {Kamiran, Faisal and {\v Z}liobait{\.e}, Indr{\.e} and Calders, Toon},
    Da = {2013/06/01},
    Date-Added = {2020-03-03 10:35:51 +0100},
    Date-Modified = {2020-03-03 11:27:38 +0100},
    Doi = {10.1007/s10115-012-0584-8},
    Isbn = {0219-3116},
    Journal = {Knowledge and Information Systems},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {613--644},
    Title = {Quantifying explainable discrimination and removing illegal discrimination in automated decision making},
    Url = {https://doi.org/10.1007/s10115-012-0584-8},
    Volume = {35},
    Year = {2013},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {https://doi.org/10.1007/s10115-012-0584-8}}

@url{initiative21,
    Author = {Initiative D21},
    Date-Added = {2020-02-12 11:46:59 +0100},
    Date-Modified = {2020-02-12 11:47:49 +0100},
    Title = {Bias in algorithmischen Systemen},
    Url = {https://initiatived21.de/app/uploads/2019/03/algomon_denkimpuls_bias_190318.pdf},
    Year = {2019},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {https://initiatived21.de/app/uploads/2019/03/algomon_denkimpuls_bias_190318.pdf}}

@url{data-service-alliance,
    Author = {Expert Group Data Ethics},
    Date-Added = {2020-02-10 13:27:59 +0100},
    Date-Modified = {2020-03-09 14:33:56 +0100},
    Title = {Ethischer Kodex f{\"u}r daten-basierte Wertsch{\"o}pfung},
    Url = {https://data-service-alliance.ch/_Resources/Persistent/456771f49480bcdc65113a52fd994933be9184d2/Codex_V3_german_public.pdf},
    Year = {2019},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {https://data-service-alliance.ch/_Resources/Persistent/456771f49480bcdc65113a52fd994933be9184d2/Codex_V3_german_public.pdf}}

@inproceedings{EthicalCode,
    Author = {M. {Loi} and C. {Heitz} and A. {Ferrario} and A. {Schmid} and M. {Christen}},
    Booktitle = {2019 6th Swiss Conference on Data Science (SDS)},
    Date-Modified = {2020-03-09 14:28:29 +0100},
    Doi = {10.1109/SDS.2019.00-15},
    Issn = {null},
    Keywords = {business data processing;data analysis;ethical aspects;public organizations;administrations;ethical code;data-based business;industry-academic initiative;Ethics;Guidelines;Companies;Pipelines;Law;ethics, data, algorithm, predictive models, fairness, privacy, algorithmic bias, code},
    Month = {June},
    Pages = {6-12},
    Title = {Towards an Ethical Code for Data-Based Business},
    Year = {2019},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {https://doi.org/10.1109/SDS.2019.00-15}}
```

Screenshot appendix: 
[image]

Screenshot with `(?, ?)` and the corresponding Tex:

```
Die Autoren des ''Quantifying explainable discrimination and removing illegal discrimination
 in automated decision making'' Papers 
\cite{quantifying-explainable-discrimination} unterscheiden zwischen erklärbaren und illegalen Diskriminierung.
```

[image]

Are there any obvious issues you see in my document?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you run `bibtex` and then `latex` two more times? See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)

Comment: If I remove all the references to things I don't have in your MWE (`\loadglsentries{glossary}`, `\include{cover}`, `\include{document1)`, `\include{document99)` - the latter two are even syntax errors) and clean up the rest I'm left with https://gist.github.com/moewew/df1f150e68ed110a68c4bd18079b7066. If I run that MWE I get errors like `! Undefined control sequence. \hyper@@link ->\let \Hy@reserved@a`. If you dig around in the apacite documentation a bit, you find the following passage in §8.2 *`hyperref`, `backref`, and `url`*: ...

Comment: ... "[...] `apacite` is compatible with `hyperref`, provided that `apacite` is loaded *after* `hyperref`". And indeed, when I switch the order of the `hyperref` and `apacite` calls, the example I linked above compiles fine (after LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX) and produces a nicely linked citation looking like "(Kamiran, Žliobait˙ e & Calders, 2013)" with links and all and no question marks.